# WPF : MVVM Microsoft.Expression.Interaction

Tags: wpf, mvvm, interaction, delegatecommand

I am working on MVVM , I have used interactions.
[image: XAML Binding]

Purpose is what ever will be typed in text box, same will be displayed in `TextBlock`.

Interaction trigger will be done event `PreviewTextInput` of text box.

But it is giving error but not working as expected.

Binding error at runtime image has been attached.

Below is the code.

**XAML**

```
<Window x:Class="MVVMApp.TextBindings"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MVVMApp"
    xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    
    Title="Text Bindings" Height="450" Width="800">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="100"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="100"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="100"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="100"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="100"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="100"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="100"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="200"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="200"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="200"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="200"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Text="Enter Text Value" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"/>
    <TextBox Name="txtBox1" Text="{Binding BxVal,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Width="150" Height="30">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewTextInput">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding cmdType}" CommandParameter="{Binding BxVal,ElementName=txtBox1}"></i:InvokeCommandAction>
            </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </TextBox>
    <TextBlock Text="Result --> " Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"/>
    <TextBlock  Text="{Binding Result,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Background="Lavender" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"/>
</Grid>
```

MVVM

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MVVMApp.Helper;
namespace MVVMApp.ViewModel
{
class TextBindingsVM :ViewModelBase
 {
    
    DelegateCommand <object> cmdType { get; set; }
    
    private string _Result { get; set; }
    public string Result
    {
        get { return _Result; }
        set
        {
              _Result = value;
               OnPropertyChanged(this, "Result");
        }
    }
    private string _BxVal { get; set; }

    public string BxVal
    {
        get { return _BxVal; }
        set
        {
            _BxVal = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(this, "BxVal");
            Result = BxVal;
        }
    }

    public TextBindingsVM()
    {
        cmdType = new DelegateCommand<object>(cmdType_Execute);
    }

    private void cmdType_Execute(object obj)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I see no 'binding error at runtime' image

Comment: Sorry,i have added image now, XAML Binding

Comment: Change your binding CommandParameter to "{Binding DataContext.BxVal,ElementName=txtBox1}. Also you do not required event trigger for this specific scenario, result text can be binded directly to inpurt text

Comment: No offense, but you just have a dump of meaningless code.
For example, you set the binding `{Binding BxVal, ElementName = txtBox1}`, but the TextBox does not have the `BxVal` property!
Or you have specified in the command the execution of the `cmdType_Execute` method, but this method has nothing but throwing an exception!
It will be much easier if, instead of explaining **HOW** you implement the task, you describe **WHAT** you want to implement.

Comment: After changing command parameter tro DataContext.BxVal the error is gone, but delegate command i.e. cmdtype still it showing error in Bindingpath

Comment: The expected output is,The Text which is being typed in textbox  should be displayed in text block,which is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. Actually INotifyPropertyChanged was not implemented in ViewModelBase class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MVVMApp.Helper
{
    class ViewModelBase:INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void OnPropertyChanged(object sender, string PropertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName));
            }
        }
    }
}
```